# How can I create a protocol for a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift

I have a few `UITableViewCell`'s that have a few different layouts depending on if they're teammates, enemies, etc. But I have to treat each type differently etc. So I tried to cut down on replicated code by using a protocol,

I've created a protocol for a `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
protocol ViewCellProtocol {
    var teamRank: UILabel! { get set }
    var ranking: UILabel! { get set }
    var rankDelta: UILabel! { get set }
    var upDownIndicator: UILabel! { get set }
    var textLabel : UILabel? { get }
}
```

This is my class:

```
import UIKit

class TeamStatsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var teamRank: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ranking: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rankDelta: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var upDownIndicator: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Then when I try to use it

```
 func playerViewCell(_ tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> ViewCellProtocol {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamNameCell")! as! TeamStatsTableViewCell
        let rank = sections[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]["rank"] as? Int
        let (rating, ratingDelta) = selectRating(section: indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)
        let indicator = decideRatingIndicator(ratingDelta: ratingDelta, cell: cell)
        cell.upDownIndicator?.text = "\(indicator)"
        cell.teamRank?.text = "#\(rank!)"
        cell.ranking?.text = String(rating)
        cell.rankDelta.text = String(format: "%.0f", ratingDelta)
        cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]["username"] as? String
        return cell as! ViewCellProtocol
    }
```

I get an error:

> Could not cast value of type '.TeamStatsTableViewCell' (0x1008d35d8) to '.ViewCellProtocol' (0x10ea37db8).
>   2018-04-24 22:00:27.137516-0600[434:72294] Could not cast value of type '.TeamStatsTableViewCell' (0x1008d35d8) to '.ViewCellProtocol' (0x10ea37db8).

I wish it would tell me what part it doesn't conform to. Any suggestions? Fairly new to swift kind of looking at `protocols` like `interface{}` in Go. Thanks.

Comment: Well, taking `class TeamStatsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {` and `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "teamNameCell")! as! TeamStatsTableViewCell` into consideration, `return cell as! ViewCellProtocol` can't possibly work, as `TeamStatsTableViewCell` does not conform to `ViewCellProtocol`

Comment: I would further argue, based on your current approach `playerViewCell` should be accepting an instance of `ViewCellProtocol` directly and not be trying to look it up itself

Comment: So I googled the answer previous to posting this question and could not find anything referencing a solution to this kind of problem. So I ask the question, it receives a -1 and a vote to close. This is why this website is just becoming a massive meme.

Comment: Because you didn’t correctly implement the protocol against your class before you tried to cast it, that’s our fault? Any basic tutorial on protocols would have shown you what you needed to do. SO isn’t a replacement for basic documentation or tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom cell class might be implementing all the stuff that's in the protocol, and that'd be enough in objC perhaps, but here you must declare that you implement that protocol explicitly

```
class TeamStatsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, ViewCellProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var teamRank: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ranking: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rankDelta: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var upDownIndicator: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that `TeamStatsTableViewCell` conforms to `ViewCellProtocol`, for example by adding this extension:

```
extension TeamStatsTableViewCell: ViewCellProtocol { }
```